# How to use gitolite public & private key pair generated for windows in linux in virtual box?

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have generated public and private key pair for git in windows and it is working fine in windows. And I tried to use the same key pair in linux in virtual box by copying the .ssh folder to ~/.ssh folder of linux.
Now when I try to perform git commands like clone, fetch in linux it is asking for password. I haven't specified any password for this. How to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my : ls -la ~/.ssh

```
user@g3gdev-user:~$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 28
drwxrwxrwx  2 user user 4096 Jun 21 11:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 43 user user 4096 Jun 23 10:59 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    1464 Jun 21 11:05 git_key.ppk
-rw-------  1 user user 1464 Jun 21 11:05 git_new_key.ppk
-rwx------  1 user user 1675 Jun 21 11:05 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 user user  400 Jun 21 11:05 id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user user  415 Jun 21 11:05 known_hosts
```

Comment: it sounds like you have a problem with the ownership and/or the access rights of the files in ~/.ssh on your linux system. Edit your post and add the output of `ls -la ~/.ssh`

Comment: your .ssh directory and id_rsa have the wrong access rights. Change them to: `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 id_rsa`.

Comment: Is id_rsa  the converted verison of the git_key.ppk? Is the git_key.ppk the git key from windows?

Comment: @SebastianStigler:yes

Comment: If you open the id_rsa file in an editor it should  start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. If it starts with  `---- BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----` you have used the wrong convertion method (Export ssh.com) in puttyGen.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have to open the generated key in puttyGen, and then go to Conversion, then Export to openSSH. Use this openSSH for your linux systems. There is a small difference between openssh and ssh.